# Cannot load image from /public directory in react, next.js, typescript setup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, next.js

With my image in the public directory, I am getting 404 not found with

```
<img src="/signature.png" />
```

I have been stuck on this for hours and have no idea what's going wrong. Anyone have an idea on what is off? Code below

My .babelrc is

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

packages.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "next": "^10.0.3",
    "next-ga": "^2.3.4",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.14",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  }
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "/src/public/*"]
}
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok - resolved after way too long :facepalm: /public needed to be in the root directory (so same level as node_modules) and not in /src - hope this helps someone else!